# gcc versus as-ld for debugging purpose , not hit on gdb breakpoints

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb, gnu-assembler, breakpoints

My platform is ubuntu i686 (32 bits)

If i compile a assembly source with gcc driver with debugging options :

```
gcc -nostartfiles -g -o toupper toupper.s
```

I open the toupper executable with gdb debugger integrated on emacs editor

```
$ emacs toupper.s-> M-x gdb -> M-x gdb-many-windows
```

I generated a breakpoint on first instruccion with

```
(gdb) b _start
(gdb) run
```

When i start the execution wiht run command the debugger stop on _start label, correctly.

If I compile the same source toupper.s with as assembler and link with ld linker:

```
as -g -o toupper.o toupper.s
ld -o toupper toupper.o
```

Now the steps for debugging matched the gcc case.

```
$ emacs toupper.s -> M-x gdb -> M-x gdb-many-windows
(gdb) b _start   -> mark with a red point the _start line
(gdb) run -> DONT HIT THE _start LINE ¿?
```

I see that the symbole table is correct, the breakpoints mark it is correct but the execution is NOT step by step.

I have display de verbose steps on gcc case and tried it again with as/ld case but the result is the same

¿ There is some default option on gcc case that not matched the as/ld case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your problem that debugger doesn't stop on your breakpoint?

Comment: And by the way, why use -nostartfiles? It compiles either way.

Answer (score 1):

When you build with `gcc -nostartfiles -g ...`, GCC (at least my GCC on a Linux system) passes `-gdwarf2` to `as`. You can see the actual `as` command if you add `-v` to gcc's invocation.

When you build with `as -g ...` directly, you are not passing `-gdwarf2`.

I am guessing *that* is what explains the difference in behavior. I am not sure what `-g` means to your version of `as`, or why it should matter.

Comment: Thanks. Doesnt matter -g or -gdwarf2 option for assembler. The difference between gcc front-end linking process and ld (binutils linker)  is that gcc link with collect2 program. If you exec collect2 linker after as assembler the result is correct, but if you do the linking phase with ld the postdebugging step by step fail. It need set the ld linker with some options  for match the collect2 equivalente linker.  ¿ Which? . Thanks.

Comment: @candido On Linux, `collect2` simply execs `ld`. As far as I can see, it doesn't add any new options. You can see the actual `ld` command that `collect` invokes by running `strace -v -fe trace=execve collect2 ...rest..of..collect2..args`.

Comment: @  Employed Russian , the linker ld needs link with shared libs like `libgcc.so` and `libc.so` for table symbol resolution. I dont know why. So the next options are a solution : `ld  -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2   -L/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3  -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -o toupper toupper.o`